# use dict of function in UDF

Tags: pyspark, user-defined-functions

In pySpark, I have a dataframe `df` as follow:

```
Site    A   B
1       3   83
1       16  26
1       98  46
1       80  14
1       83  54
2       0   83
2       75  67
2       72  24
2       60  13
6       40  50
6       34  60
6       36  39
6       68  6
6       91  51
6       81  82
```

or the other side, I have a dictionnary `myDict` of functions `g = {1 : f1, 2 : f2, 3: f3, 6:f6}`

I want to use the dictionnary to generate a new column. Something like :
`df.withColumn("MyCol", myDict[df.Site](df.A, df.B))`

But when I do that like this, I receive the error:

> unhashable type: 'Column'
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> TypeError: unhashable type: 'Column'

How should I write it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

The `withColumn` function only accepts existant columns in the same dataframe as arguments or a literal through the `lit()` function (`lit` actually returns a column).

In order to pass in extra parameters you must use a [higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) that returns a `udf`:

```
class MyUDFs():
    @staticmethod
    def trans(myDict):
        def cb(Site,A,B):
            return myDict[Site](A, B)
        return udf(cb, StringType())

df = df.withColumn("MyCol",MyUDFs.trans(myDict)(df["Site"],df["A"],df["B"]))
```